# Calculate the main memory consumption of ImageMagick convert when appending images

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I append several PNG images with the ImageMagick `convert` tool.

```
convert -set colorspace RGB `ls *.png` -append outout.png
```

This are the color parameters of the input files:

```
$ identify input1.png
input1.png PNG 9600x1800 9600x7200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 355KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

4 input files exist with identical parameters.

The output file has these color parameters:

```
$ identify output.png
output.png PNG 9600x7200 9600x28800+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.461MB 0.000u 0:00.009
```

This is the ImageMagick version I use:

```
$ convert -version 
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-04-09 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

How can I calculate the main memory consumption of the `convert ... -append` operation?

Comment: `/usr/bin/time -f "%M" convert .... -append out.png` maybe?

Comment: How can I use the time command to calculate the memory consumption of a command? The time command can be used to measure the execution time and the CPU time of a command.

Comment: And also to measure the peak memory usage.

Comment: Now I learned that I need to install "GNU time" (/usr/bin/time) and that it is much more powerful than just "time". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the Q16 version of ImageMagick and this version of ImageMagick uses 16 bits per pixel channel (The Q8 version uses 8 bits per pixel). In ImageMagick 6 each pixel has 4-5 channels per pixel (red,green,blue,opacity, index), this behavior is going to change in ImageMagick 7 (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#channels). Since your input and output are both a png file you are using 4 channels per pixel, this totals to 16*4 = 64 bits per pixel. Because your input images are 9600x1800 and you are combining 4 of them into a single image you will need a total of 64*9600*1800*4 = 4423680000 bits / 552.96 MB to allocate the images in memory. But because a copy of each image is created when the output image is created you will need twice that amount of memory: 1.1 GB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I think there are two mistakes. 16*4 = 64 and not 48 bits per pixel. And 9600x28800 is just the page geometry information. This is because I forgot the "+repage" option during a "convert -extract ...". The real pixels are the 9600x1800. I think (hope!) the real pixels are what counts.

Comment: I found out someting strange. When I append e.g., four images with the  resolution 6400x1200 each to create an image with the resolution 6400x4800, this should require 6400x4800*64=1,966,080,000 Bits => 245,760,000 Bytes. But in practice I observed with the command top that the convert process requires approx. 500 MB main memory during execution. Why does the process require approx. the double amount of main memory?

Comment: I forgot that a copy is created when you make the output image. I have updated my answer.